# Why is The Constructor Expecting a class When I put an Array as a Parameter - JavaFx

Tags: javafx, constructor

I am working on a javaFX project that expects the user to press a button to store information inputed on the text fields. What is stumping me is how to pass the String values that I have collected from the text fields into the other class, DisplayStage, that I made to display the stage of the values input by the user. My instructor, says that I am supposed to pass the array of the strings by using the constructor of the other class I created, DisplayStage. This is what I tried:

```
btnAdd.setOnAction((e) -> {
            
            // i keeps count of how many times the button was pushed
            this.i++; 
            //Setting the size of the array to be as big as how many times it was clicked
            String [] dataEntries = new String [this.i];  

            //Inside info, we will store the Data inputed by the user
            info =  txtID.getText() + " , " + txtName.getText() + " , " + txtAdress.getText() + " , " + txtCity.getText();
            
            // At index i-1 of dataEntries[], store the new entry stored insode of info
            dataEntries[i-1] = info;
            
            DisplayStage saveNewEntry = new  DisplayStage(dataEntries[]);        
        
        });
```

the constructor in the DisplayStage class expects a String array.

What I found out from putting this into practice is that, constructors are not like methods and you cannot pass an array like this, instead, by looking at the *compilation* error message I know that I am supposed to reference a *.class*. I might be missing something like a special Syntax that I can use to pass the array to the constructor or maybe I should create a class that stores the data from the user and then reference that class inside the constructor?

Thank you.

Comment: *"constructors are not like methods and you cannot pass an array"* - Yes you can.  *"by looking at the error message"* - And what is that error message?  What exact line of code does it refer to?  How is `DisplayStage` defined?  How is `dataEntries` defined?  If `dataEntries` is already an array, what is the purpose of the `[]` square brackets in this usage?  Why not just pass `dataEntries` itself?

Comment: Got it, it will edit with more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass arrays in constructors just like any other objects by name:

```
DisplayStage saveNewEntry = new DisplayStage(dataEntries);
```

And your constructor can be defined like this:

```
public DisplayStage(String[] values) {
   // Your code
}
```